Chart Js; Bar chart; Can the X axis labels be simply left aligned/justified rather than appearing centered?
Can the labels on the X axis be left aligned/justified as opposed to appearing centered like the following example?
i.e. the requirement is that the label should be aligned with the grey vertical separation line of each bar.
Original X Axis Labels
Left Justified X Axis Labels
I have read the documentation and it seems it maybe possible via "ticks:" using the "userCallback function overrides" to modify the x-axis label itself, but I am unsure if I am over complicating this, and if this is the correct way to do it - And then if it is the correct way, then what ticks: attribute/option/parameter is required to left justify the label?
Or is there a simpler way other than using ticks/userCallback?
Snippet of code...
xAxes: [{
  ticks: {
    userCallback: function(value, index, values) {
      return value ??? Not sure what return here/ barWidth???
    }
  }
}]

Thanks

Which version of Chart.js is this?

It is Chart version 3.6.2

For version 3.6.2, the default x axis  is set up as options: {scales: {x: {ticks: .....}}}, so there's no xAxes array, see the migration guide, for instance the first code example. Also, the ticks callback is called callback not userCallback, see the docs.

If you want to have the ticks to the left, you may want to test setting offset: false, see the docs, or using ticks.labelOffset. In any case, the question misses a [mre] and as such cannot be given a good answer.

Chart.js alignment is described in this page: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/legend/title.html
The x ticks alignment has three values, start, center (default) and end.
In your case, the following code should work (I didn't test it).
new Chart(handler,{
  options: {
...
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          align: 'start',
        }
      }
    }
  }
})

